# How many valid programs can you write?

Tags: code-challenge

## Backstory:

I think that my boss might finally realize that I don't any enough work, despite being paid by the hour. I want to throw him off track, by writing as many valid programs as I can to send to him. Unfortunately, due to budget cuts, my keyboard only allows each key to be pressed once.

## Specification:

Write as many different valid programs as you can for your language. You may not reuse any character at any time (even within the same program). A program is "valid" is it compiles and runs without any errors (warnings are acceptable), for any given input. Your score is the number of unique programs written.

It does not matter what the program actually does. It does not need to take input, produce output, or even terminate. The only restriction is that may never return an error.

## Example (JavaScript):

1. `b=1`
2. `alert(2)`

Comment: "Any given input" is a bit problematic, we often define that input can be taken as command line arguments, and most compilers/interpreters will crash given some random argument. How about any input through one particular method chosen by the answerer? For complicated challenges like this I'd personally recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625).

Comment: Open virtual keyboard, no keys pressed, any byte entered [/sarcasm]

Comment: Does "any given input" mean it's up to us because later on it says "It does not need to take input"?

Comment: How do you define "return an error"?

Comment: I voted to close as unclear because of the "any input" issue. (It's labelled as too broad because that's what the majority chose.)

Comment: Another thing to verify for reopen votes: do you mean "character" (in which case [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) wins) or "byte"?

Comment: When you say, "You may not reuse any character at any time," does that include `'\n'`?

Comment: If this gets reopened, I have dibs on Brainfuck; 1114104 programs (every Unicode character other than `<>+-.,[]`)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think it would be fair to say that there is a couple of languages that would tie.  For example every single character program for Cubix qualifies for this challenge, as they would never be hit and terminating is not a requirement in this challenge.

Comment: There are plenty of languages in which all possible strings of characters are valid programs. This isn't a very interesting challenge in those languages.

Comment: Yes, this is problematic in many esoteric languages, but it can be a very interesting challenge in others! My recent "How high can you count" challenge resulted in two gold badges and is somewhat similar to this one. A few suggestions off the top of my hat: 1. Ban languages where every single character is a valid complete program (e.g. Pingpong). 2. Ban symbol independent languages (Lenguage). 3. Require that the program does _something_ (to disallow "programs" that consists of no-ops). 4. Skip the "any input" rule. I suggest you change the rule to: "The programs may optionally take input.".

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) version 16.0, <s>83</s>84 programs

```apl
⍝ empty program
 ⍝ single space
	⍝ single tab
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
+
-
×
÷
⌈
⌊
*
⍟
|
!
○
~
∨
∧
⍱
⍲
<
≤
=
≥
>
≠
≡
≢
⍴
,
⍪
⍳
↑
↓
?
⍒
⍋
⍉
⌽
⊖
∊
⊥
⊤
⍎
⍕
⌹
⊂
⊃
∪
∩
⍷
⌷
→
⎕
1 2 3           ⍝ input for above program
⍞
Hello, World!   ⍝ input for above program
/
⌿
\
⍀
¨
&
⍨
⌶
#
⊆
⊣
⊢
⌸
⍸
⍝
⋄
L:
⍬
{}
⍝ just a newline
⍝ this line belong with the previous one
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY@5SgNRFIZr/6c4QbDQJGYSjQsurYW9jc2ExCCOucO4EVwQlSGZJaASU7knGMXGBY2FCOZN7ovoP1jYCB74zj37Ode0rUS@bFqq@EWBoAcpGEgjgyEMI4sRjGIMA0ig20D3FTqoEA/90OE5thCDbvjYga60yQ2jD@QRE9DVJiapW5iiviCX5IrZZ8Sp78gTtHtIjjFN74j4pMoN79DeCSd6fFukyXiN1Jl7o79H9pnnlMot49FlxOWMWh2GpCUjv6LDU1ks2WursqAcMXNqvSC2o4qOuczeM8wULEvFZU45Vj72T/0gN31gnn27@Gyjjwa/HrygF1Gb9lxRJassG8pZWuEUMbLJVJLnXhN@P@j81IWdP@qiFLR/gNlxmvfY3Aa@AQ) (except for two which cannot run on TIO's version 15.0)

#### Explanations:

Most of the programs just print their content. Exceptions are:

- The four whitespace ones do nothing.
- `→` terminates
- `⎕` asks for evaluated input
- `⍞` asks for character input
- `⍝` is a comment
- `⋄` is a statement separator (i.e. two statements that each do nothing)
- `⍬` prints an empty numeric list (i.e. just a newline)

Comment: @Uriel I keep forgetting that this isn't that other challenge.

Comment: Yup. These should already have a tag, like polysnippets or something else

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 225 programs

```
(empty program)
¢
¤
¥
¬
®
µ
½
Æ
Ç
Ñ
×
Ø
Œ
ß
æ
ç
ð
ı
ȷ
ñ
÷
ø
œ
  (space)
!
$
%
&
(
)
*
+
,
-
.
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
:
;
<
=
>
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
N
O
P
Q
R
S
U
V
W
X
Y
[
]
^
_
a
b
c
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
u
v
w
x
|
~
¶
°
¹
²
³
⁴
⁵
⁶
⁷
⁸
⁹
⁺
⁻
⁼
⁽
⁾
Ɓ
Ƈ
Ɗ
Ƒ
Ƙ
Ɱ
Ɲ
Ƥ
Ƭ
Ʋ
Ȥ
ɓ
ƈ
ɗ
ƒ
ɦ
ƙ
ɱ
ɲ
ƥ
ʠ
ɼ
ʂ
ƭ
ʋ
ȥ
Ạ
Ḅ
Ḍ
Ẹ
Ḥ
Ị
Ḳ
Ḷ
Ṃ
Ṇ
Ọ
Ṛ
Ṣ
Ṭ
Ụ
Ṿ
Ẉ
Ỵ
Ẓ
Ȧ
Ḃ
Ċ
Ḋ
Ė
Ḟ
Ġ
Ḣ
İ
Ṁ
Ṅ
Ȯ
Ṗ
Ṙ
Ṡ
Ṫ
Ẇ
Ẋ
Ẏ
Ż
ạ
ḅ
ḍ
ẹ
ḥ
ị
ḳ
ḷ
ṇ
ọ
ṛ
ṣ
ṭ
ụ
ṿ
ẉ
ỵ
ẓ
ȧ
ḃ
ċ
ḋ
ė
ḟ
ġ
ḣ
ṁ
ṅ
ȯ
ṗ
ṙ
ṡ
ṫ
ẇ
ẋ
ẏ
ż
«
»
‘
’
“
”
```

224 characters in Jelly's 256-byte codepage are valid, non-error-throwing programs on their own, plus an empty program. The other characters could be used in literals, but since all the literal-denoting characters are already in use on their own, no new programs can be made from them.

All of these were tested, one by one, on [tio.run](https://tio.run/#jelly).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Not according to the [codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page). Are you thinking of a linefeed?

Comment: Oopsie yes I was!

Comment: You could add `t€`, `d/` and `s\ `.

Comment: The rules are rather unclear to me, but many of these programs [error](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o////mQqJuQqpRUX5RQA) given certain inputs.

Comment: The `any input` might trounce this count :( (was about to suggest changing `d/` to `t/` and adding `dþ`).

Comment: Yeah... string input would break nearly all the arithmetic atoms. Shame. The rules are a tad unclear so my fingers are crossed for my answer!

Comment: You can add the program that consists of a single newline.

Comment: @Adám that would be the pilcrow (same byte).

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, Jelly can understand both when using Unicode, and since this isn't code-golf, you should.

Comment: @Adám Hmm it says "character" so I guess literally speaking, they are different programs even though they are the same program. Looks like a win for Lenguage.

Comment: @Adám I see your point, but since Jelly's default is to use that codepage, I would say they're the same character. There are a few other consensuses saying basically "go with whatever your language uses" so I'm confident in saying that here.

Comment: @Christian Is that really the default? [TIO certainly uses Unicode](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/jelly).

Comment: @Adám if a language defines its own codepage, it makes sense to define its encoding based on that codepage, does it not?

Comment: @Christian No, then you *may* use an encoding based on that code page. The prototypical example would be [APL](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9428/43319), which *can* use its code page. but can also use Unicode when advantageous. In fact, I do so in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126512/43319), to maximize my score. If I didn't, I'd have to leave out three of my programs, `⌸`, `⊆`, and `⍸`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python REPL, 24 programs

```
[empty]
[space]
[tab]
[newline]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
sum
pow
chr
next
id
()
{}
[]
#
\
```

Comment: How about this set of six... `sum, pow, id, all, chr, next`? Also `_` is valid.

Comment: @JonathanAllan `all` isn't valid because internal repeats aren't allowed.

Comment: @xnor oh yeah :p well five there, maybe there is another set of six somewhere...

Comment: ...in which case `hash`, `''`, `...`, and `""` must go.

Comment: @JonathanAllan `_` on a clean repl would throw a name error - it is assigned only after each evaluation

Comment: Ahha, yes, that it would, good catch.